# Proof there exists a vector under certain constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

This question is a basic optimization problem, also a linear algebra question:

**Let $x$ be a feasible point for the constraints
$Ax=b$, $x\geq0 $ 
that is not an extreme point. Prove that there exists a vector $p\neq0$ satisfying
$Ap=0$, $p_i=0$ if $x_i=0$.**

(We know that by the definition of basic solution, the columns of $A$ corresponding to nonzero entries of $x$ are linearly dependent, but what then? 
Thanks.)

Comment: Looks somewhat similar to the statements of farkas lemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m$ and $n$ be the number of rows and columns of $A$, respectively.

Let $x$ be a feasible point that is not an extreme point. This means that $A$ and $x$ can be written without loss of generality as:
\begin{align}
A&=\begin{bmatrix}
B|C|N\end{bmatrix},&
x&=\begin{bmatrix}
x_B\\x_C\\x_N
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x_B\\x_C\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where $B$ is an invertible $m\times m$ matrix, and $x_B$, $x_C$ have non-zero components.

Now, define $\bar{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{x}_B\\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$, where $ \bar{x}_B=B^{-1}b$. By construction, we have $A\bar{x}=b$.

Consider then $p:=x-\bar{x}$. We now have:
$$Ap=Ax-A\bar{x}=b-b=0$$
while 
$$p=\begin{bmatrix}
x_B\\x_C\\0
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{x}_B\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x_B-\bar{x}_B\\x_C\\0
\end{bmatrix}$$
so that $p_i=0$ whenever $x_i=0$.

Comment: +1 nice! but it doesn't seem to need the fact $x>= 0$